# Determine Unique Device?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to distinguish what device my app is using. E.g. if they switch from their phone to their tablet.

Would this work? Or is there another way to identify a unique device?

```
Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you saving the flag? In a SharedPreference file? If so, disable automatic backups in your Manifest file.

Comment: @Zun No it's being saved on the database itself (Firestore) after I've downloaded it.

Comment: You know, providing these details is important because no one knows what you mean with `and I'm downloading data from a database.`

Comment: you can store fcm of downloaded devices as per user and check on application start

Comment: @Zun I more wanted to know how best to identify a unique device

Comment: @Ashish I more wanted to know how best to identify a unique device

Comment: This really sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ArthurAttout I'm just gonna leave context out next time. Does the question fit more now?

Comment: Providing context is fine, your original question just failed to ask a proper question related to your **actual problem**.